# Is it possible to add rectangular corners to layout?

Tags: android

android studio 3.6

I need add rectangular corners (white color) of my layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/containerCameraView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/min_height"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scanHinttextView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView
                    android:id="@+id/cameraView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:keepScreenOn="true"
                    app:cameraAudio="off"
                    app:cameraMode="picture"
                    app:cameraPictureFormat="jpeg"
                    app:cameraRequestPermissions="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Smt like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible try this alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733079/setting-the-background-of-an-xml-layout-to-camera-in-android

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59454788/2016562)